# Add items from collection 1 to collection 2, if collection 2 doesn't contain item from collection 1

Tags: clojure

I've got two maps:

`(def people {:1 "John" :2 "Paul" :3 "Ringo" :4 "George"})`

```
(def band 
  {:data 
    {:members 
      {:1 {:id 1 :name "John"} 
       :2 {:id 2 :name "Paul"}}}})
```

I want to loop over `people` and add any members that don't exist in `[:data :members]` to `band`, resulting in:

```
(def band 
  {:data 
    {:members 
      {:1 {:id 1 :name "John"} 
       :2 {:id 2 :name "Paul"}
       :3 {:id 3 :name "Ringo"}
       :4 {:id 4 :name "George"}}}})
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
(for [[id name] people]
  (when-not
    (contains? (get-in band [:data :members]) id)
    (assoc-in band [:data :members id] {:id id :name name})))
```

Which yields:

```
({:data 
   {:members 
     {:4 {:id :4, :name "George"}, 
      :1 {:name "John", :id 1}, 
      :2 {:name "Paul", :id 2}}}} 
 nil 
 nil 
 {:data 
   {:members 
     {:1 {:name "John", :id 1}, 
      :2 {:name "Paul", :id 2}, 
      :3 {:id :3, :name "Ringo"}}}})
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting back what looks to be a list of each mutation of `band`. What am I doing wrong here? How can I add the missing members of `people` to `band [:data :members]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be pedantic you aren't getting back *any* mutation of band. In fact, one of the most important features of Clojure is that the standard types are immutible, and the primary collection operations return a modified copy without changing the original.

Also, `for` in Clojure is not a loop, it is a list comprehension. This is why it always returns a sequence of each step. So instead of altering an input one step at a time, you made a new variation on the input for each step, each derived from the immutable original.

The standard construct for making a series of updated copies of an input based on a sequence of values is `reduce`, which passes a new version of the accumulator and each element of the list to your function.

Finally, you are misunderstanding the role of `:keyword` syntax - prefixing an item with a : is not needed in order to construct map keys - just about any clojure value is a valid key for a map, and keywords are just a convenient idiom.

```
user=> (def band 
            {:data 
              {:members 
                {1 {:id 1 :name "John"} 
                 2 {:id 2 :name "Paul"}}}})
#'user/band
user=> (def people {1 "John" 2 "Paul" 3 "Ringo" 4 "George"})
#'user/people
user=>  (pprint
         (reduce (fn [band [id name :as person]]
                    (if-not (contains? (get-in band [:data :members]) id)
                      (assoc-in band [:data :members id] {:id id :name name})
                      band))
                  band
                  people))
{:data
 {:members
  {3 {:id 3, :name "Ringo"},
   4 {:id 4, :name "George"},
   1 {:name "John", :id 1},
   2 {:name "Paul", :id 2}}}}
nil
```

You may notice the body of the `fn` passed to `reduce` is essentially the same as the body of your `for` comprehension. The difference is that instead of `when-not` which returns nil on the alternate case, I use `if-not`, which allows us to propagate the accumulator (here called `band`, same as the input) regardless of whether any new version of it is made.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I wasn't aware of the difference between `when-not` and `if-not` - very helpful!

Comment: Question about `[id name :as person]` in the function signature - did you include `:as person` to make it clear that `id` and `name` are attributes of a person? Is this an idiom? I think it definitely makes the intent of the code clear.

Comment: Yes, you can also refer to `person` after that to indicate the whole collection, but I just included it to help convey intent (I like to give an :as name to destructurings unless I have a compelling reason not to)